# Find the global maximum and minimum of this function

Tags: calculus, functions

I need to find the global maximum and minimum of the function $f(x,y)=2x^3-3x^2+y^2-2y$. For the critical points, I get $\nabla f(x,y)=(6x^2-6x,2y-2)$. Which results in $x=0, 1, y=1$. Next, I want to find the global maximum and minimum. Since this there is no interval of restriction on this function, I need to find the highest and lowest point of this 3D function, how do I go about doing that?

Comment: If you put $y = 0$ and vary $x$, what happens? What happens when $x$ is negative and $|x|$ is increasing? What happens when $x \gt 1.5$ and is increasing

Comment: There is another critical point. The equation $6x^2-6x$ has more than one solution, try to factor out the root you've found

Comment: Indeed as the answer below says, the global maximum and minimum are $\infty$. The dominant term is a cubic, (which is shaped around by the quadratics), however cubics always have global maxima and minima at $\infty$, $-\infty$, (since there is no restriction on the domain: the quadratics and linear terms themselves do not restrict the domain).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x,0)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(2x^3-3x^2\right)=\infty$$ and $$\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x,0)=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\left(2x^3-3x^2\right)=-\infty$$
this function doesn't have global extrema. Are you sure that there isn't a restriction on the domain of $f$?

Comment: good, this is helpful